# re- installing R linux ubuntu: unmet dependencies R

Tags: r, ubuntu, package, apt-get

I used aptitude install to install a package, Ubuntu 11.10 oneiric, that apparently I couldn't install because of dependencies. I removed a couple of more libraries while doing it. I uninstalled Rstudio but still can't install R on my machine. I'm on ubuntu and this is what I get while running 
sudo apt-get install r-base

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 2.15.3-1quantal0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 2.15.3-1quantal0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

any ideas how to start from scratch and get R running again?

More of the Error log:
The following packages have unmet dependencies r-base-core : Depends: libblas3 but it is not installable or libblas.so.3 but it is not installable or libatlas3-base but it is not installable Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.13-20ubuntu5.3 is to be installed Depends: liblapack3 but it is not installable or liblapack.so.3 but it is not installable or libatlas3-base but it is not installable Depends: liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614) but it is not installable –

Comment: Have you followed the instructions at http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/ ?

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies
r-base-core : Depends: libblas3 but it is not installable or
                        libblas.so.3 but it is not installable or
                        libatlas3-base but it is not installable
               Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.13-20ubuntu5.3 is to be installed
               Depends: liblapack3 but it is not installable or
                        liblapack.so.3 but it is not installable or
                        libatlas3-base but it is not installable
               Depends: liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614) but it is not installable

Comment: Maybe we should have started with "what version of Ubuntu?"

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 11.10, oneiric

Answer (score 15):

Try this

If you have added a line from new ubuntu repository to /etc/apt/sources.list, erase the line.
Then, run the commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rrutter 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It worked for me, the answer comes from here
http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Upgrading-on-Ubuntu-from-2-11-1-to-2-15-1-td4636965.html

Comment: this worked for me, although the update took a long time -- about 35 minutes

Comment: Just removing lastly added R repositories from /etc/apt/sources.list was enough for me

Answer (score 2):

1. Uninstall previous R installation:

   ```
   sudo R --no-save
   pkgList <- installed.packages(priority='NA')
   remove.packages(pkgList)
   q()
   sudo apt-get remove --purge r-cran* r-base*
   ```
2. Follow instructions (for R part) from:
   [How to install R, JGR and Deducer in Ubuntu](http://r-interface.blogspot.com/2012/04/install-r-jgr-and-deducer-in-ubuntu.html)

Comment: Following those instructions is proving hard since I can't seem to find the code name for the most recent release.

Answer (score 0):

To list what you installed with aptitude type the following

```
xyz@sxyzcom~$ sudo apt-get remove
```

This should list what remains of your R install and possibly anything else missing dependencies Then you can run

```
xyz@sxyzcom~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and that should get you back to square one.

Comment: After running the commands above, while doing                        sudo apt-get install r-base-dev This is what I get:                                                                                         The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-dev : Depends: r-base-core (>= 2.15.3-1quantal0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: I did, the installation and the maintenance section. I changed some of the files on the sources.list adding new apt keys ,etc. simply trying everything that I could thought could have gone bad. This is what it all ends in:                                                        
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing problems regarding Broken packages then first of all remove that package by first checking dependencies and then forcefully remove that package, and don't ever forget to reboot when you do make enormous changes in your system. To remove that package use these shell commands

```
$ sudo su
```

Then Enter your password

```
# apt-cache rdepends package-name
# apt-get --purge remove --force package-name
```

Use these shell commands

```
# apt-get clean
# apt-get autoclean
# apt-get update
# apt-get upgrade
# apt-get dist-upgrade
# reboot
```

This worked for me, Try this, I believe this will fix all your problems, Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the package forcefully,you can do

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq package_name
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get update
```