# How to install R package in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: r

I get following error while installing R in ubuntu 12.04.

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-core

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-core : Depends: libblas3 but it is not installable or

               Depends: liblapack3 but it is not installable or

               Depends: liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614) but 5.1.1alpha+20110809-3 is to be installed
               Depends: libtiff5 (> 4.0.0-1~) but it is not installable

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: it may help...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260250/re-installing-r-linux-ubuntu-unmet-dependencies-r/15620874#15620874

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Try to install it through Ubuntu Software Center. Search for R software.

Or try to fix it with the command:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

That command will try to find and install any missing dependencies.

For others solutions you can check this link:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Comment: +1 for pointing to askubuntu.  However, This really is a *library* question.  It appears either the ubuntu R package for Precise is incomplete (perhaps for the unspecified OS the OP is using).

Comment: Thankyou I installed using Synaptic Packet Manage. Its working fine now.