# Installing R Language on Ubuntu 16 - unmet dependencies

Tags: r, ubuntu, docker, apt-get

Installing the R language following the instructions at the site [ [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-16-04-2) ] .

During installation I receive an error "**unmet dependencies**" at the r-base component using the apt-get install command. See the log with the command sequence below:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
Executing: /tmp/tmp.QQyv0HB7mS/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
keyserver.ubuntu.com
--recv-keys
E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
gpg: requesting key E084DAB9 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key E084DAB9: "Michael Rutter <marutter@gmail.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1

/data/shared/datascience# add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=s390x] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/'

apt-get update
Hit:1 https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial InRelease  
Get:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Get:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Get:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/main s390x Packages [554 kB]
Get:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/universe s390x Packages [494 kB]
Fetched 1252 kB in 12s (104 kB/s) 
Reading package lists... Done

apt-get install r-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.4.0-1xenial0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 3.4.0-1xenial0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-doc-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is this an error in my install procedure, or is this packet broken?

Comment: I tried the same steps in a dockerfile from ubuntu 16.04 and it worked. Only thing I had to change was the url to get the key: `hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80` but don't think it has to do with it.

Comment: Maybe this question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260250/re-installing-r-linux-ubuntu-unmet-dependencies-r

Answer (score 1):

By using the Universal Ubuntu repository and command shown below, the issue was solved:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```