# Installing r-base; Depenency: r-recommended missing?

Tags: r, dependencies, ubuntu-16.04

Hello I am trying to install r-base for Ubuntu 16.04.

I have followed the steps at https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html

However I am getting a 'unmet dependencies' error when I run `sudo apt-get install r-base`

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    r-base : Depends: r-recommended (= 3.4.4-1xenial0) but it is not going to be installed
>
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Any ideas for getting around this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [re- installing R linux ubuntu: unmet dependencies R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260250/re-installing-r-linux-ubuntu-unmet-dependencies-r)

Comment: What happens if you  do `sudo apt-get install r-base r-recommended`?

Comment: I get a similar 'unmet dependencies' error regarding r-recommended with a list of 7 missing dependencies.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt --fix-broken install` followed by `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: Just ran all 3 on my machine. The first command yields >0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded

Comment: second command: "Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rrutter/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                  
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease          
Hit:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Hit:5 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ InRelease
Reading package lists... Done"
And third command yields same result as the first...

Comment: So does R work now when you type R + <Enter> in a terminal?

Comment: It appears to be working! Thank you so much!

Comment: dobis32 can you please post a self-answer?

Comment: Yes, I have just posted a self-answer

Answer (score 3):

Running the following commands seems to have solved my problem:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

Running the following fixed it for me, but this solution uses r-base-dev not r-base (r-base still didn't work).

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

Make sure to check in the software and properties that if your restricted and universe repositories are enabled. Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631191/issues-in-installing-r-base-dev) with more information.

Comment: `r-base-dev` instead of `r-base` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I started getting this issue because I added the wrong apt-repository for my version of Ubuntu (focal fossa instead of bionic).

Solved by doing `sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list`, then deleting any lines containing `focal`